# SpriteKit simple shapes not drawing

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm doing some experimentation with SpriteKit and am roadblocked on a concept that to me seems very simple. I'm trying to draw simple shape (ie: square, circle) to the screen.

```
    var testNode = SKSpriteNode()
    testNode = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.orangeColor(), size: CGSizeMake(20, 20))
    testNode.position = goalPoint
    testNode.color = UIColor.orangeColor()
    self.addChild(testNode)
```

According to the developer documentation for `SKSpriteNode`

> An SKSpriteNode is a node that draws a textured image, a colored square, or a textured image blended with a color. You can also provide a custom shader to create your own rendering effects.

Apparently I'm missing how to do the colored square. I was able to create an SKTexture and get a sprite to appear, but without one I've been unable to get geometric shapes to appear.

I also attempted to use the `SKShapeNode` class but was unable to get that to appear either. I assume I'm missing something simple. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in itself is correct, the only two things I can think of to be the problem is:

1. goalPoint - Is somewhere out of the screen bounds.
2. The location of the code. Where is your code located in your project?

In my didMoveToView I have the following :

```
var testNode = SKSpriteNode()
        testNode = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.orangeColor(), size: CGSizeMake(20, 20))
        testNode.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
        testNode.color = UIColor.orangeColor()
        self.addChild(testNode)
```

And it works like a charm.

So relocate your code to somewhere you are sure it's executed. And make sure goalPoint is within the screen.

Good luck :)

Comment: I figured out the issue, and it was along the lines of what you said. I had defined a point at (200,100). To my surprise, SpriteKit defaults the landscape orientation coordinate system, so the screen only shows roughly the x-coords between 300-700, so to my shock 200 is out of bounds. Great catch Thanks!